# How can I sort a 2-dimensional array in Perl by columns, ignoring some columns?

Tags: perl, sorting

I have a 2-dimensional array in Perl. I want to sort the columns in the array but I want to ignore the leftmost n columns. I want to sort by the values in row 0.

Let me clarify what might be a confusing description. I have a table like this:

```
Z W D F E C
0 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0 1
```

I want to ignore some number of columns on the left, say the first two. I want to sort the remaining columns by the value in the first row. The end result is this:

```
Z W C D E F
0 1 5 2 4 3
6 7 1 8 0 9
```

How would I do that in an elegant way? I understand how to use comparison functions to do the sort but I don't see how to tell Perl to ignore the first n columns.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here with the mutlidimensional array ?

Comment: How is your 2D array set up - by column or by row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a relationship between the old order and the new order.

The following creates an array of indexes `@new_order` which can be used to sort each row:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = map { [split] } <DATA>;

my @old_header = @{ $data[0] };
my %old_order = map { $old_header[$_] => $_ } ( 0 .. $#old_header );

my @new_header = ( splice( @old_header, 0, 2 ), sort @old_header );
my @new_order = @old_order{@new_header};

# Output Transformed Data
for (@data) {
    print "@{$_}[@new_order]\n"
}

__DATA__
Z W D F E C
0 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0 1
```

Outputs:

```
Z W C D E F
0 1 5 2 4 3
6 7 1 8 0 9
```